# Migrating Maintenance Plan from One Sql Server 2008 Instance to Another

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, copy, data-migration, maintenance-plan

I have an extensive maintenence plan on one sql server 2008 instance that I wish to move to 4 other instances.  What is the best way to do this other than rebuilding it on each server?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try connecting to integration services on the server, expand msdb, maintenance plans and export the plan.

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't get it to work. No help on dba... http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29346/ssis-package-to-create-maintenance-plan-fails-silently. On MS forums an MVP said it couldn't be done? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/dcc8eceb-5e23-40b8-a529-1f2e8d278415/ Who's right?